# Error on generating models in Umbraco 7.6 in ModelsBuilder API mode

Tags: api, model, umbraco, umbraco7

I have Umbraco 7.6

I am trying to enable `ModelsBuilder` in API mode.
As far as I learned in my version of umbraco `Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.Api` should have already been part of the `Umbraco.Core` and installed.

However when I check in my Developer > ModelsBuilders tab I can see this:

```
ModelsBuilder is enabled, with the following configuration:

The models factory is enabled.
The API is enabled but not installed.
External tools such as Visual Studio cannot use the API.
No models mode is specified: models will not be generated.
Models namespace is Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.
Static mixin getters are enabled. The pattern for getters is "Get{0}".
Tracking of out-of-date models is not enabled.
```

In my `web.config` I have this:

```
  <add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.Enable" value="true" />
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.EnableApi" value="true" />
  <add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" value="Nothing" />
```

Since it says:

```
The API is enabled but not installed.
```

I tried to install `Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.Api` but have not found any information which `ModelsBuilder` versions are compatible with Umbraco 7.6 so I installed the latest 8.0.4 into my start Web project.

I installed VS extension and created a separate project to hold models eg. `MyProject.Umbraco.Models`, right-clicked `Builder.cs` file and clicked 'Run custom tool' (which I previously set up in the `Builder.cs` properties.

It does something but at the end it throws an error:

```
UmbracoModelsBuilder: Starting v8.0.4 10/05/2019 18:29:01.
UmbracoModelsBuilder: UmbracoModelsBuilder failed to generate code: UnsupportedMediaTypeException: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IDictionary`2' from content with media type 'text/html'.
UmbracoModelsBuilder:    at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.Api.ApiClient.GetModels(Dictionary`2 ourFiles, String modelsNamespace)
   at Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.CustomTool.CustomTool.UmbracoModelsBuilder.GenerateRaw(String wszInputFilePath, String wszDefaultNamespace, IntPtr[] rgbOutputFileContents, UInt32& pcbOutput, String& errMsg)
```

Anyone can help with this?

**EDIT**

I have created my Api project and installed `UmbracoCore`, `ModelsBuilder` and `ModelsBuilder.Api` - same versions as my Web project (I think it's 3.0.7 ModelsBuilder version, not 8.0.4 as I originally tried) - so no installation is missing in the API or Web project.

Comment: Is this a new project? if so why don't you use Umbraco 7.13+  or even better 8? There have been some improvements in how the model builder works in more recent versions.

Comment: @Ayo not it's not a new project and I can't simply upgrade. Sorry but it's a silly comment and helps nothing.

Comment: @nickornotto hey man, no APi is not core, You have to install it. It's a package. It's not hard to install and configure:

[Jon jones' post on ModelsBuilderAPI](http://www.jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-developers-guide/strongly-typed-models-within-umbraco/using-umbracomodelsbuilderapi-to-create-strongly-typed-models-within-umbraco). Follow this post and you'll have it working in about 10 minutes. Let me know if it helped you I'll post it as an answer. I'm also seeing you're trying to install the latest ModelsBuilder (I think) Which is for Umbraco 8, not 7. Try an older one

Comment: ModelsBuilder and ModelsBuilder.Api is already part on my umbraco 7.6, I only had to install them in the MB Api project - the same version that is used with Web project (I think it's 3.0.7 for 7.6, not 8.0.4). Also UmbracoCore has also been installed in the Api project. I have edited my post. @Jabberwocky

Comment: No, I said I added more information @Jabberwocky

Comment: @nickornotto If you're saying you added the correct version, what's the error now? It it still complains for 8.0.4 it means you think you've installed the correct version, but you're actually wrong.

Comment: The error stays the same, just different version